# DNS forwarding used to point GoDaddy DNS to Heroku app: this doesn't work from a corporate network -why?

Tags: dns

My domain on GoDaddy is set up with DNS forwarding to the Heroku app - this works fine from all of the internet connections I've tried except for the one at work. How can I troubleshoot this issue? Is it a case of ports being blocked? Why might that matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do believe that this sounds a lot like one of two problems.  This solution does assume that you have recently setup the domain forwarding, such as in the last 24 - 72 hours.  If this is the case then the solution may also find itself since it could be just a longer then normal delay on the propagation of the domain changes.

1. The DNS server that is used from the corporate network has not been updated with the correct address to point your domain to.  Sometimes some DNS servers take a bit of time before they become aware of a record change.  This is one reason why when your are setting up your IP address for your systems it allows for a primary and secondary DNS server IP.
2. The DNS cache that is maintained on some network gateways and or systems may need to be updated or flushed.  This process can be a bit equipment specific depending on what equipment is access permissions are involved.

Comment: thanks, what are my options here? Email the IT department and ask them to clear the DNS cache?

Comment: Yes you can do that or if you wait it should update itself.  It normally will do so fairly regularly, but depending on the settings on the DNS server that the company uses it could be longer.  If nothing else it would not hurt to ask them to either clear the cache or at least clear the domain in question.